# Files details from folder

Tags: r, file, dataframe

I'd like to loop through a list of files and record detailed info about them (size, no. of rows, means of columns).

I just started with storing the info in a data frame:

```
df<-data.frame()
all <-list.files(pattern=".csv")

for (i in all){
  file<-read.csv(i)

  filas<-nrow(file)
  cols<-ncol(file)

  info<-c(i,filas,cols)
  df<-rbind(df,i,filas,cols)
}
```

but it triggers an error caused by the 'i' variable, which is just a file name. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,          p.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `for` loops. Rather, use `lapply` in combination with `do.call` to obtain your desired result. Try:

```
 do.call(rbind,lapply(all,function(x) {y<-read.csv(x); c(file=x, filas=nrow(y), cols=ncol(y))}))
```

Your approach was failing because in order of `rbind` to work, you need two data.frames with the same number of columns. You initially have created an empty data.frame (with 0 column) and this couldn't be `rbind`ed to a vector of length 3 (assuming that you want a row for each file showing file name, number of rows and number of columns). If you really want to use a `for` loop, you should do something like:

```
     for (i in 1:length(all)) {
        file<-read.csv(all[i])
        info<- data.frame(file=all[i], filas=nrow(file), cols=ncol(file))
        if (i==1) df<-info else df<-rbind(df,info)
     }
```

Comment: Perhaps also explain to OP why the `rbind` was failing?